# Where is there a discussion where one can understand Devarim 23:25 fully?

Tags: halacha, parsha-torah-portion

According to Devarim 23:25 כִּי תָבֹא בְּכֶרֶם רֵעֶךָ, וְאָכַלְתָּ עֲנָבִים כְּנַפְשְׁךָ שָׂבְעֶךָ; וְאֶל-כֶּלְיְךָ, לֹא תִתֵּן.

Where is there a discussion where one can understand Devarim 23:25 fully? For example, is it implied in this passage the size of the vineyard, if it is an open or enclosed vineyard, how often one can do this, etc...? If not, then one might see a number of problems:

such as, but not limited to: no knocking at the vineyard entrance, if any, needed, that is, no permission to enter the vineyard needed, just eat all you can, as long as each fruit goes directly to your mouth and not into a container, and you can do this any day of the week, except shabbat, etc....

An observant vineyard-owner can even deduce from this passage that s/he can not injure or kill anybody who enters, i.e. trespass, his/her vineyard (so a vineyard trespasser is better off selecting vineyards owned by observant Jews in States where one can pull a gun on a trespasser, no?)?

Answer (score 1):

Rashi on the spot points out various restrictions to this verse.

(Source : Sefaria)

> כי תבא בכרם רעך. בְּפוֹעֵל הַכָּתוּב מְדַבֵּר:
>
> כי תבא בכרם רעך WHEN THOU COMEST INTO THE VINEYARD OF THY FELLOW MAN, [THEN THOU MAYEST EAT GRAPES AT THY FILL] — Scripture is speaking of a laborer (who is engaged in gathering in the grapes, but not of one who is doing other work in the vineyard, nor of one who enters the vineyard with no intention to do work; cf. Rashi in the next passage) (Bava Metzia 87b).
>
> כנפשך. כַּמָּה שֶׁתִּרְצֶה:
>
> כנפשך means as much as you like.
>
> שבעך. וְלֹא אֲכִילָה גַסָּה (בבא מציעא פ"ז):
>
> שבעך AT THY FILL — but not excessive eating (Bava Metzia 87b).
>
> ואל כליך לא תתן. מִכַּאן שֶׁלֹּא דִּבְּרָה תוֹרָה אֶלָּא בִּשְׁעַת הַבָּצִיר, בִּזְמַן שֶׁאַתָּה נוֹתֵן לְכֶלְיוֹ שֶׁל בַּעַל הַבַּיִת (ספרי; בבא מציעא פ"ט), אֲבָל אִם בָּא לַעֲדוֹר וּלְקַשְׁקֵשׁ אֵינוֹ אוֹכֵל (שם פ"ז):
>
> ואל כליך לא תתן BUT THOU SHALT NOT PUT ANY IN THY VESSEL — From here we may derive that Scripture is referring only to the period of the vintage, to the time when thou puttest grapes into the owner’s vessel, — then thou mayest eat but not put any into thy vessel; but if he comes to hoe or to weed (i.e. to do other work than harvesting) he must not eat of the grapes (Bava Metzia 89b).

This verse is the topic of a good chunk of the 7th chapter of Bava Metziah ([87a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.87a.19) - [93a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.93a.14)). There you'd find all the parameters.